# Center and stretch button in TableRow

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, mobile

I have this code

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    />

    <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</TableRow>
```

And it looks like this
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSLx0.png)

I need to center this button and stretch to the size of other table rows, i.e. to the size of the authorization form. For example, the screenshot below

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PoFr.png)

I tried with `android:stretchColumns="1"` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your code and was able to create what you are looking for in the following manner

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Login" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>
```

As the documentation shows the *stretchColumns* attribute is "The zero-based index of the columns to stretch". By giving it the value * we say we want all columns to stretch evenly. And by playing with the layout weight we can change the size of the different views. Hope this helps you. IMO you should look at using Relative or Linear layouts for relatively simple UI's like these, or perhaps even the very forgiving Constraint layout.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. I found another way with stretchColumns = 1. https://imgur.com/1eue5Xh
https://pastebin.com/2TdampS0

Comment: No problem, good to see you're exploring to find solutions!